# Google App Engine on Google Apps Domain

Tags: google-app-engine, dns, alias, google-apps, verification

I'm having trouble getting my domain pointed to my website hosted with google app engine. Here's the background... take care to separate the concepts of "google apps" (domain hosting, email, etc.) and "google app engine" (website framework).

I have a domain that's using Google Apps for Your Domain, let's call it company.com. So my login for my google apps account is bob@company.com. I have a different domain that is aliased back to my google apps account, let's call it mycompany.com. It's been successfully aliased and registered with my primary google apps account using the cname method, and has updated mx records. We have a ton of domains, and I only want to use one "google apps" account to maintain them all.

Now I have a website I've built using google app engine, and the url is effectively mycompany.appspot.com. I want to get mycompany.com to point to my website that currently resides at mycompany.appspot.com.

There's a spot in the google app engine dashboard under application settings where you can add a domain. So I click there and enter mycompany.com and I get an error message saying that domain is not using google apps.

If I back up to the page I submitted, there's a note saying I need to register the domain with google apps. So I click the link to do that and enter mycompany.com and I get an error message saying the domain has been registered and is in the process of ownership verification. But that process is already finished.

So... what do I do? Does google app engine not support a domain that is only aliased to a primary google apps account? Does mycompany.com need to have its own primary google apps account?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I ran into this problem setting up my domain.   It's a little counter-intuitive, but you'll want to add (in your example) company.com to your appengine account.   Once you add company.com, you'll see a dropdown listing all of the domains that belong to your hosted google apps account, including mycompany.com.

Comment: This is correct. Alternately, you can add the app from the Google Apps end, in which case it's much more intuitive in this situation.

Comment: Awesome, thanks Nick. I hadn't seen that this can be done from the apps side.

Comment: Is this answer out of date?  It seems that this is no longer possible.

Comment: can anyone please tell me how can i remove previously added domains so that i can reverify them again.