# domain aliases and Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, dns, google-apps, domain-aliasing

I have a Google Apps domain at www.openstv.org that I use for email and a website.

I recently created a Google App Engine app at stv.appspot.com and it can also be accessed at opal.openstv.org.

I would like to:

1. Use www.opavote.org for my Google App Engine app instead of opal.openstv.org, and
2. Have opavote.org be a domain alias of openstv.org so that I don't have to maintain two Google Apps domains.

Two stackoverflow questions suggest that this is possible:

1. [Google App Engine on Google Apps Domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478283/google-app-engine-on-google-apps-domain)
2. [Google App Engine and domain name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532300/google-app-engine-and-domain-name)

But other reputable information suggests that it is not possible: [Issue 638](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=638)

I've tried to do this, but I can't get it to work.  Is there an explanation for this apparent contradiction?

EDIT: Adding what I tried in response to Nick's comment.

From App Engine Dashboard:

1. Go to Application Settings
2. Click Domain Setup
3. Enter opavote.org -> "Sorry, you've reached a login page for a domain that isn't using Google Apps. Please check the web address and try again."
4. Click back and enter openstv.org -> Takes me to Google Apps for Openstv.org
5. From Google Apps Dashboard for OpenSTV.org -> stv settings (my GAE app) -> Click add new URL
6. I'm allowed to enter a subdomain of openstv.org (e.g., opal.openstv.org) but I am not allowed to use the opavote.org domain (there is no dropdown menu for the domain).
7. Go to Google Apps -> Domain Settings -> Domain Names and see that opavote.org is listed as a domain alias and is verified in two ways (DNS record and uploading file).  No other options here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've added 'opavote.org' as an alias, it should be showing up in the list - this sounds like a bug with Apps. Have you tried removing it and re-adding it? If that doesn't work, you may need to file an issue with the Apps team. It's definitely possible to do this - I'm running apps off alias domains myself.

Comment: unless I'm confused, it seems that Issue 638 (just fixed the link) is a feature request for exactly what I want, and Guido responded last month that they won't be able to support this.  Would appreciate clarification on that.

Comment: @Jeff The bug describes an issue adding the alias in the Apps admin console, not with adding the App Engine app to that alias. I just verified on my own Apps domain, and I'm able to add alias domains just fine.

Comment: As I said, I have an Apps domain with multiple aliases, and I'm running App Engine apps on it with no trouble whatsoever.

Comment: It looks like my problem was with multiple sign-in.  It seems that Google Apps interacts with Google Webmaster tools and if those two have different users logged in, then things break.  I think I'm all set now.

Comment: I believed you, but was wondering if Google employees might have special privileges. :)

Comment: it's not posible http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&hlrm=en&answer=182081